# Deal with different directories in bash cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

### The problem...

I use trick77's IP blacklist script to configure the firewall of my apache server and am able to run his script in terminal.

However, when assigning the ***[bash script in ipset-blacklist](https://github.com/trick77/ipset-blacklist/blob/master/update-blacklist.sh)*** to crontab, it will not run no matter what I do.

### Code written in crontab file for root:

```
@daily /var/bash/update-blacklist.sh
```

### What I think is the culprit...

Since I haven't done this sort of thing before, I believe that the `PATH` of the bash script isn't set correctly... but again, I'm not sure.

I have seen others using a line such as `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` to resolve problems involving the script's location, but, I don't exactly know what this does.

I set the location of the bash file to `/var/bash` instead of `/usr/bin` and I believe that this is throwing things off.

**Pardon my lack of understanding. I really am a beginner when it comes to bash.**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

### What I have done...

#### Per @EtanReisner:

1. Added `echo here >> /tmp/update-blacklist.out` to top of `update-blacklist.sh` and set cron to run it every minute (`* * * * *`).

   The file was successfully created.
2. Added `type -p curl grep egrep ipset >> /tmp/update-blacklist.out` to top of `update-blacklist.sh` and returned:

`-p: not found
curl is /usr/bin/curl
grep is /bin/grep
egrep is /bin/egrep
ipset: not found`

Comment: Does the script have the eXecution bit set ?

Comment: @sputnick Yes, I can run it in terminal, and it has execution permissions when I view it in `ls -l`

Comment: The location of the script itself doesn't matter as long as you use the full path to the script in the cron entry. Are you sure the script itself isn't running or is the script perhaps failing somewhere inside it? If you add `echo here >> /tmp/update-blacklist.out` to the top of the script do you see that file created/updated?

Comment: @EtanReisner It's possible that the script is failing... but I don't know why because I can run it just fine in terminal: `sudo /var/bash/update-blacklist.sh`

Comment: Is crond is running ? Try to search errors in system logs if the response is 'yes'

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes... I added `echo here >> /tmp/update-blacklist.out` and set cron to run it every minute and it created that file.

Comment: Where did you add that in the script? What do you see in the file if you add `type -p curl grep egrep ipset >> /tmp/update-blacklist.out` to the script? What about if you add (different test) `set -x; exec >/tmp/u-b.out 2>&1` to the top of the script?

Comment: @EtanReisner 1.) I added that to the top of the script. 2.) [added to top of script] `-p: not found curl is /usr/bin/curl grep is /bin/grep egrep is /bin/egrep ipset: not found` 3.) What does that do? (I want to know before I add it to the script)

Comment: Note that the `-p` option to `type` is a bash extension: basic /bin/sh (which is cron's default shell) does not know about it. Most likely the problem is inside your script, which you have not shown.

Comment: @glennjackman The script is linked in the question.

Comment: So `ipset` could not be found in the script context. So you need to fix the PATH so that it can be. The `set -x` block turns on command tracing which prints out the commands that will be run before running them. Though at this point it seems like that fixing the PATH to include the location to `ipset` will likely fix (or at least wildly improve) the situation.

Comment: @EtanReisner That's sort of what I had thought. What PATH attribute should I add? Put it in an answer so that I can give you points. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @EtanReisner ipset is at `/usr/sbin/ipset` BTW...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `type ipset` indicated that `ipset` was not in the cron script `PATH` which isn't surprising.

The default `PATH` for cron jobs is fairly limited.

With `ipset` located in `/usr/sbin` that is the path that must be added to the cron script's `PATH` variable.

You talked about this in your question

> I have seen others using a line such as PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin to resolve problems involving the script's location, but, I don't exactly know what this does.

What that does is set the `PATH` variable to those paths (from whatever the default value was).

The `PATH` variable contains the paths where the shell looks for binaries/scripts/etc. to run when you try to run them as commands.

Comment: So... add `PATH=/usr/sbin` to the top of the script?

Comment: No, that will break commands that live in any other location. You can use the line you listed if you want a full set of `PATH` or if you just want to add `/usr/sbin` to the path then use `PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin`.